# New UITableViewCell not drawing properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a cell defined in a storyboard, and I have

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TTEntry" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

which gives me a cell, and then I can configure it, and it displays fine.

However, when I try to add a new cell by using

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

the result is a new cell that is half initialised and half drawn.  When I select the cell, the rest draws, but with some of it uninitialised.

It feels like the storyboard hasn't completed creating the UI objects for the cell by the time it returns the cell from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

I'm assuming I'm doing something stupid, but I've re-read the UITableView manual again, and looked over all my code, and all I can think of is that there is a race condition happening somehow.

Incidentally, the failure pattern appears the same each time I run it - the second and third cells created this way always look wrong, then the 4th seems ok but doesn't gain focus, the 5th fails again and the 6th works perfectly.

**Update 09/06/15**
I've continued tried the old "comment almost everything out and see if it works" trick, and I've found that the lines that seem to be causing the problem are:

```
UILabel *label;
label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numerator[indexPath.row]];
```

within the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

So it seems it's not happy with updating the label text at this point, which is a shame since the label is no good without being updated.

Should updating a label like this work in this method, or am I just using the wrong type of view?

Comment: Would it be possible to share some code involving the insertion of objects in the datasource side plus the cell configuration ?

Comment: My datasource is just a series of arrays in the ViewController since the data is very simple, so the view controller is the TableView's delegate and datasource.